# How do I Test Protected Methods?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, model-view-controller

I have wrote a costumer attribute  that depends on another property. I must do a Unit Test but the method is protected. How can I test it?

```
public class PWCustomerAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string name;
    public string prename;
    public string emaill;

    public PWCustomerAttribute(string nom, string prenom, string email) : base() {
        name = nom;
        prename = prenom;
        emaill = email;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
           var property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(name);
            if (property == null) { throw new ArgumentException("Property with this name not found"); }
            var nameV = (string)property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

            property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(prename);
            if (property == null) { throw new ArgumentException("Property with this name not found"); }
            var prenameV = (string)property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

            property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(emaill);
            if (property == null) { throw new ArgumentException("Property with this name not found"); }
            var emaillV = (string)property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

            string chaine = value.ToString();
            foreach (string s in ChainAValider(chaine)) {
                if (nameV.Contains(s)||prenameV.Contains(s)|| emaillV.Contains(s))
                {
                    var msgErreur = FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName);

                    return new ValidationResult(msgErreur);
                }
            }
        }


        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
```

My test:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void AttibuteTest()
    {

        string firstName = "Yaaaaaa";
        string lastname = "Donald";
        string Email = "a@a.com";


        var value = "1!Yaaaaaa"; 
        var context = new ValidationContext(value);
        var attrib = new PWCustomerAttribute(firstName, lastname, Email);
          var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

          var result = attrib.IsValid(value, context);//, context);

    }
```

Comment: If you can't meaningfully test the private methods of a class via the public methods then that would suggest something is wrong with the design of the class. If it is hard to test the class so that you wish to break down the tests to test a subset of its functionality then I would suggest breaking the class into its logical pieces and testing those individually.

Comment: You could create a Validator class with a public IsValid method. Or just put the IsValid public...